# How can I cause an on and off switch to carry over to another view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

```
- (void)controlsEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    self.onSwitch.enabled = enabled; 
    if (enabled)
    {
        NSLog(@"ON");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"OFF");
    }
}
```

Basically I need to implement this function where it will affect another view controller. If the switch is on it will do a certain method inside another view controller.

Comment: So send a message to the other view controller.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a pointer from the `SecondViewController` to the view controller that has the variable `onSwitch`.

If you have that reference all you need to do is something like this.

```
- (void)methodOnTheSecondViewController
{
    if (self.pointerToFirstViewController.onSwitch.enabled) {
        //Do something if ON
    else {
        //Do something if OFF
    }
}
```